# descendantOf() causes js error in ie

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

New to prototype, googled this trouble but didn't find any solution. Works fine in other browsers but alerts an error in ie

```
        Event.observe(document.body, 'click', function(evt) {
        var element = evt.target;
        if ('sign_in' != element.id  && 'customer_link'!= element.id && !element.descendantOf('sign_in') && !element.descendantOf('customer_link'))
        {$('sign_in').hide();$('customer_link').removeClassName('poped');}
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
var element = evt.element();
```

instead of

```
var element = evt.target;
```